# How to calculate distance to a specific slope value (in degrees) from each data point on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, distance, slope

I'm using QGIS. Before this, I managed to get an attribute table showing depth/slope of each data point. Now, I’d like to add an additional column that shows the distance of each point to a slope value. So say for example I choose to specify a slope value of 1 degree, what would the distance be from point A/B/C etc to the nearest slope that is 1 degree?

But first I need to calculate the distance to slope from each data point which I can't seem to figure out. My slope values were derived from terrain analysis.

Comment: All the data is in one file? If so you could export the 1 degree slope values into a second file and use the tool distance matrix (from the vector-analysis menue) to calculate the distances to the points in the first file.

Comment: I have a slope raster file from DEM which I tried to convert to point data layer through r.to.vect but it's taking forever. Do you know of another way to do this? I don't have a file with the 1 degree slope values.